# Probability of a symmetric distribution in a set divided into two subsets

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

There is a set of 100 randomly generated integers and we know that 50 are odd and 50 are even. If we divide this set into two subsets of random sizes, choosing the contents based on characteristics unrelated to eveness, what is the probability that within each such subset the distribution of odd-even integers is equal (=p), e.g. 20-20 in one and 30-30 in the other?

Is it possible to calculate p without knowing the specific sizes of both subsets?

When analyzing subsets after knowing their size I thought the proper way is to use the binomial distribution formula for one subset having equal distribution as the second one will then have to follow this pattern given that the total number of even and odd integers is equal. However, this seemingly causes two different p's for the same event as the probability of equal distribution will be always higher in the smaller subset,even though its content is not independent of the larger subset.

Answer (score 0):

(BIG) HINT

Assume you pick $O$ odd numbers for set $1$, and $E$ even numbers for set $1$. Then set $2$ has $50-O$ odd numbers and $50-E$ even numbers.

The ratios are therefore $\frac{O}{E}$ and $\frac{50-O}{50-E}$ respectively, so they are equal when:

$$\frac{O}{E}= \frac{50-O}{50-E}$$

Working this out:

$$\Rightarrow O(50-E) = E(50-O)$$

$$ \Rightarrow 50O-EO = 50E-EO$$

$$\Rightarrow 50O= 50E$$

$$\Rightarrow  O=E$$

So, setting aside the case where a set has no even numbers at all, what is the probability of $O=E$?

Comment: When you put it that way the answer seems to be 1/49. But does this take into account the fact that whenever a subset is filled in randomly in terms of eveness-oddness, so each object is equally probable to be odd or even, outcomes with close ratio of even-to-odd are more likely than outcomes strongly swaying one side or the other.